# How to display only one post on first category page and rest on next pages?

Tags: posts, categories

My question is as above. I am going to use a category template specific for this category and would like to show the first, if possible the sticky post for this category, post on the first page and 5 posts of the category on the next pages. I have searched a lot but didn't find a working example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"specific for this category"*: Is it specific to a static single category? And though off topic, but I'd like to ask, why do you need such a look at you category page?

Comment: I am using a category template page (category-ID.php) for this category because it has to look different. In this case I think it just looks better to have only the first post on the first page and then be able to go to the next page where are more posts.